# I am haveing some issues with a post method, i am getting {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}

Tags: python, http, fastapi, uvicorn

I am new to developing in general and I am trying to figure out why i keep getting {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"} here is a snipit of what i have. I am printing the http variables on the site so I know i am getting correct values. in this case strategy.id == 1 and stock.id == 1 I have checked the sql statement by manually running it in a sql viewer as
INSERT INTO stock_strategy (stock_id, strategy_id) VALUES (1, 1)
and that works as well. I am sure i am just missing a comma or some other little thing, but i cannot for the life of me find it.

```
    <form method="post">
        <select name="strategy_id">
            {% for strategy in strategys %}
            <option value="{{ strategy.id }}">{{ strategy.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="stock_id" value="{{ stock.id }}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Apply strategy" />
    </form>



@app.post("/apply_strategy")
def apply_strategy(strategy_id: int = Form(...), stock_id: int = Form(...)):    
    connection = sqlite3.connect(config.db_path)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO stock_strategy (stock_id, strategy_id) VALUES (?, ?)
    """, (stock_id, strategy_id))

    connection.commit()

    return RedirectResponse(url=f"/strategy/{strategy_id}", status_code=303)
```

Comment: some console output
   output:
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [1779]
INFO:     Started server process [2300]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53644 - "POST /stock/AAIC HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Seems you are doing a POST (on form submit?) to /stock/AAIC but the server says that's not allowed.

Comment: The `<form>` tag should be `<form method="post" action="apply_strategy">`  The `action` attribute tells the browser which url is the target of the form; if it's missing, the POST request will go to the current url.

Comment: yup, i just found that. i was missing action="apply_strategy"

Comment: I cant figure out how to accept the answer.